# Server experiencing Kernel-Power Event 41, but only once every two weeks

Tags: kernel, electrical-power, server-crashes

I go to check on a client's servers once every two weeks as part of an IT contract. For the past month and a half, their secondary server will experience a sudden shutdown and generate the Critical Kernel-Power Event 41 Error in event viewer. This has been happening once every two weeks exactly. Here is the interesting part of the XML:

[[image: XML]]

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Checked the power settings to make sure the hard drive will not
   sleep, nor will the server.
2. Checked the server events around the crash time, but no event points towards anything that would tax the system or pull too much power (i.e. a storage backup). Nor are there any user inputs that would cause this, so far as I can tell.
3. Gone into %system root% to search for a MEMORY.dmp file, but to no avail. I can assume this probably isn't a BSOD event.

If this were any other situation, I might say it is some sort of hardware fault (motherboard or power supply as first guesses). But the *regularity* of the crashes is what's throwing me off. It is within an hour of the previous crash, separated by two weeks.

Anyone have any other tips to try to identify the cause or have any idea what the main issue may be? I really, really appreciate it!

Comment: i would check, if the crash is always at the same time. if yes, hunt down the scheduler

Comment: This is my question, posted as a guest. I'll add clarification where needed below.

Comment: Whatever happened, it was not a BSOD, otherwise the various "Bugcheck" fields in the event would be filled (the official name for a BSOD is "bug check"). This system didn't crash on its own. But it definitely experienced an unclean shutdown.

Comment: Side note: it might seem obvious to you, but it would be nice to at least mention you're talking about a Windows server. Also, since it seems to be a physical one, additional details (such as make and model and whether there is an UPS or not) would be useful.

Comment: Some more clarification: the device is a Dell Poweredge R440 running Windows Server 2019. It is attached to a UPS with other items that are not experiencing outages.